Get Facebook custom events associated to a pixel
I've been trying to get all the custom events that I create to using on my application, so far I have not found a way to so.
These are the events that I am trying to get to use on my UI.
I have tried trough the SDKs and API. Has anyone faced this problem?

A solution or endpoint that brings me that information.
